# Ubuntu (xenial) cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: ubuntu, bash, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm having an issue running a file ecl.e it's a 32-bit program.

I get the following if I run with bash:

```
bash /home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e
/home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e: /home/user/miniconda2
/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e: cannot execute binary file
```

and,

```
./home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e
-bash: ./home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e: No such file or directory
```

I'm running the program on x86_64. So I understand there would be in issue with not having the right libraries. I looked to fix this by getting the libraries:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 
libbz2-1.0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxmu6:i386
```

However the problem still persists.

This is the output if I run file on it:

```
file /home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, 
Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

and ldd:

```
ldd /home/user/miniconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf//bin.linux/ecl.e
not a dynamic executable
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the kernel does handle the executable format. This happens f.e. if you use the Windows On Linux subsystem of Windows 10, which runs only 64-bit executables.
If you update Ubuntu to 18.04 or 18.10, you can install a 64 bit version natively via `sudo apt install iraf`.